# Rake db:drop Not working after Upgraded ruby 1.9.3-p0 and Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant PATCH
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake.rb:27: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:31: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:77: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:150: warning: already initialized constant DeprecatedCommands
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake.rb:69: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep

Comment: after tracing found there is problem in  /Users/aditidhus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25                                                      Any help on this is appreciated ....!

Comment: What did you upgrade from?  What database?

Comment: I have upgraded ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0 to ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2. Everything works fine but not able to recreate database, in short rake  command not working. I also tried bundle exec rake command which works but gives error                                       pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "3")
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using: `bundle exec rails db:drop`

Comment: You mean to say bundle exec rake db:drop?